# Batch inflating views with same id?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater

In the recyclerview, there are about twenty items in one screen, which means, it will at least call onCreateViewHolder twenty times and each time inflate a new view with same id. Is it possible inflating them with fewer read-parse-create loops in recyclerview?

For example, if we have one view instance, can we do a deep copy to create a new view instance (without attaching to parent or root view)? If possible, we could preload them and cach them, then we could avoid the reading from resource and parsing process.

Comment: `If possible, we could preload them` RecyclerView already does this for you. `then we could avoid the reading from resource and parsing process.` This is a sign which says your architecture is incorrect. a RecyclerView should only show existing data from a List you provide. It should not retrieve data in the `onCreateViewHolder` or `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Yes, the data should be what you said, while I mean the view, not the data. Inflating view is not cheap, so I want to inflate one and clone from it to avoid the extra inflating process.

Comment: Inflating should always be cheap. Is there a reason why your code is unable to cheaply inflate a view?